# information allocation from multiple subscribers using one callback function

Tags: c++, callback, ros, subscribe

I have a C++ ROS question.

I have an assignment which requires me to get information from a number of topics generated by another program. basically. this other program makes a bunch a topics that publishes some basic data, called Pose, from the turtle simulator ros tutorials. the problem is, that I'm not sure how to get all the information I need from all the different topic sources. I know I need to subscribe to a topic to get its info, and i already know how to get all the topic names and open the subscriptions to them. what I am unclear about is whether or not i have to pass in a unique callback function into each new topic I subscribe to. or if there is a way to make one generic callback function that can be passed into all of the subscriptions.

this is my code for this so far

```
void getTTurtles(char tType, vector < TurtlePose > Tarray) {
    int i;
    string tname;
    stringstream topicName;
    //TurtlePose TPose;
    ros::master::V_TopicInfo alltopics;
    //get all topic names 
    ros::master::getTopics(alltopics);
    for (int i = 0; i < alltopics.size(); i++) {
        topicName.clear();
        topicName.str("");
        tname = getTurtlename(alltopics[i]);
        if (tname[0] == 'T') {
            Tarray[i].topicname = alltopics[i].name;
            Tarray[i].name = tname;
            topicName << "/" << TPose[i].name << "/pose";
            ros::Subscriber sub_tur = n.subscribe < turtlesim::Pose > (tname, 1, poseCallback);
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

as you can see, i have a function that get all the topic names for me. this allows me to grab only the ones whose names start with T (the purpose of the program is to get my own turtle to collect all of his created T-Turtles while avoiding his created Xturtles, so this function it meant to give me a list of the Tturtles and their locations.). I grab name of the topic names of the turtles and from that can grab the actual turtles name as well. but there is a third element i need to extract. the turtlesim::pose information that is being transmitted by all the Tturtle topics. so i use the topic name(T1,T2,T3, etc) to make a subscription to that topic and pass it a callback function, but i'm not sure how to properly write the callback function to appropriately  allocate the pose information into the proper location. for example. how to make sure that when the callback function is called as a result of /T1/pose publishing, to make sure that the information it has transmitted end up in Tarray[0].pose instead of Tarray[1] to [2], while also having /T3/pose go into Tarray[2].pose. so on and so forth.

the solution must be scalable, since the number of T-turtle topics being made can be and probably will be changed.

is their a way to write the subscription or the callback function so that you pass in a specific container at the time of creation to be used whenever that specific subscription get information from its subscribed topic?

thanks in advance for the help?

Answer (score -1):

If Your Input Data Is The Same U Can Use AnyNumber Of Subscribers With One CallBack and When Declaring Subscriber U can Pass Any Number Arguments To It So U can Separate Data That's Incoming To Your Node Inside Your Callback (by pushing it out To separate global vectors etc.)